# Faster alternative of MIN/MAX in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, partitioning

I need the lowest/highest price of stocks for the past n days. The following query works really slow. I would appreciate faster alternative:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    MIN(Close) OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY PriceDate ROWS BETWEEN 14 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS MinPrice14d,
    MAX(Close) OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY PriceDate ROWS BETWEEN 14 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS MaxPrice14d
FROM
    (SELECT CompanyID, Ticker, PriceDate, Close            
     FROM price.PriceHistoryDaily) a
```

- I need the columns specified.
- It is trailing, so I need it day by day.
- As for period, I will limit it to one year.

Comment: Please define "really slow" and "faster alternative".  These terms are open for opinion-based interpretation...

Comment: Slow as more than 20 minutes. I need to limit it at least to 10 minutes

Comment: Show table schemas and current execution plan, please.

Comment: It's slow because you are selecting EVERY ROW in your history table and then computing the min / max for each. Either limit the rows you select in the outer query (which is way over-complicated for no particular reason) or add indexing. And performance will only decrease over time as the number of rows grows (given the name "history").

Comment: Do you need this for all the rows in your table? Do you need a row per row in your table? Do you need all the columns?

Comment: I have edited my description with additional explanation

Comment: `SELECT *` is something different then `I need the columns specified`. When doing `*` no one know what columns you will get.

Comment: * are the columns in the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it doesn't affect the performance, no subquery is needed.  So start with the simpler version:

```
SELECT phd.CompanyID, phd.Ticker, phd.PriceDate, phd.Close,
       min(Close) over (partition by Ticker
                        order by PriceDate
                        rows between 14 preceding and 1 preceding
                       ) as MinPrice14d,
       max(Close) over (partition by Ticker
                        order by PriceDate
                        rows between 14 preceding and 1 preceding
                       ) as MaxPrice14d
FROM price.PriceHistoryDaily phd;
```

Then try adding an index:  `PriceHistoryDaily(Ticker, PriceDate)`.

Note:  That this returns *all* rows from `PriceHistoryDaily` and -- depending on the size of the table -- that might be what is driving the performance.

Comment: Well I don't do this because I will then use these values in another formula.

Comment: As for index. Could you please give an example. I will need to create temp table.

Comment: @Yana . . . You won't use an index because of some formula?  I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I am sorry. I have used subquery, not your simple version because This whole query will be part of another one where I will use MinPrice14d and MaxPrice14d as variables in a formula.

Comment: @Yana . . . You can use the same index with a subquery.